# How to save state of activity while starting other activity through StartActivity() method od Intent?

Tags: android

I have an `ActivityA`, which starts `ActivityB` through Intent's `startActivity()` method.The context is as below:

## A.java

```
String name = edittext.getString();  
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);  
Bundle b = new Bundle();  
b.putString("Name",name);  
i.putExtras(b);  
startActivity(b);
```

## B.java

```
Bundle bb=getIntent().getExtras();
String namee=bb.getString("name");
```

In this B Activity there will be Back button which when clicked takes control back to A as below:

```
     back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    { 
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
   Intent backToDetails = new Intent(B.this,A.class);
   startActivity(backToDetails);
}
     });
```

Now control comes to `ActivityA`. When I again start `Activity B` from `Activity A` , the previous value of the name is lost .So, I again get new Value by overwrting old value in `Activity B`. So, how to save previous name value ?
How to save the state of Activity B?
Can any one help me in sorting out this issue? 

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 2):

You just have to save the state of your activity B. In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state/151940#151940) there is a complete answer to solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: btw, if there is no saved state you should read the extra values in the Intent